# C#: Is there a way to stop a random from generating again after it has been displayed

Tags: c#

i need a way to store the random numbers generated in the parenthesis for a true/false or if statement but can't because it keeps regenerating new numbers after i input an answer. also if it generated a random of 44 and i answered 48 how do i call the random to display whether if it is correct or not?
Just a simple exercise to help myself with C# coding. Thank you for any answers given.

//There wasn't any problem with the coding at all. The problem was the Online compiler i was using, it kept refreshing every time i enter an input for answer so i thought it was giving me a new random set of numbers after it was already done with printing the entire set in the for loops. i apologize for the confusion! I don't have a visual studio so i was using an online compiler.

```
public static void Main()
{

    Random rand = new Random();
    int count, a, b, x, y;

    Console.Write("Sequence: ");
    count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Minima: ");
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Maxima: ");
    y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] roll = new int[count];

    for(a = 0; a < count; a++){
        roll[a] = rand.Next(x, y);
    }

    Console.Write("( ");
    foreach(var nr in roll){
        Console.Write(nr + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(")");

    Console.WriteLine("");
    int[] answer = new int[count];

    for(b = 0; b < count; b++){
        Console.Write("{0}. Answer: ",b+1);
        answer[b] =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question.
You already store the random numbers in roll array.

Comment: it's yet another question about generating numbers without repeating

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear what you are asking. Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: @Selvin be nice ;), your main problem is that if you read your answer your code execution is finished so you should think about how to keep it running

Comment: Your roll is not connected in any way with the answer. I guess you want something like `if (roll[b] == answer[b]) {...}`. Given that 0 < b <= a;

Comment: it's not about generating the same number 3 or 4 times, it's when the random has already displayed itself i.e "roll:( 4 50 48 6 90 )" and i input for the answer array, the roll displayed above would change to another random set of numbers i.e "roll:( 5 35 21 66 87 )" i want to ask if i can stop this from changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if(roll[i] == answer[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Question " + i + " is correct");
    }
}
```